# How to connect AWS Kinesis with C# and postman/fiddler

Tags: amazon-kinesis

I would like create client application to connect with AWS Kinesis and also connect with postman/fiddler request header.

Perquisite :

1. ARN format : arn:aws:kinesis:region:account-id:stream/stream-name
2. Default kinesis url for all :  https://kinesis.us-east-1.amazonaws.com

We have to have ARN and Key and Secret Id.

Kinesis ARN: arn:aws:kinesis:us-east-1:6333775056331:stream/template-v1-kinesis-##00056###-64-sandbox-customerstream###-Vfyubo###

AWS Key ID : ##AZG6B52DCC##
AWS Key secret : ##NG6e#p/##YGuRVEs5jqjwB4i3GLpwaewt##

So
1> what will be C# code ?
2> what will be the HTTP header input ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer 1 : Bug free C# code
Install required package

```
using Amazon;
using Amazon.Kinesis;
using Amazon.Kinesis.Model;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

     class ConsumerApp
    {
        static readonly string AWS_Key_ID = "AKIAZG6B##S7QZ##5";
        static readonly string AWS_Key_secret = "6iN###/OuYGuRVEs5jqjwB4i3GLpw###";

        static readonly AmazonKinesisConfig amza = new AmazonKinesisConfig();

        private static readonly AmazonKinesisClient kinesisClient =
            new AmazonKinesisClient(AWS_Key_ID, AWS_Key_secret, RegionEndpoint.USEast1);

private static string GetStringFromMemoryStream(MemoryStream ms)
    {
        ms.Position = 0;
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ms))
        {
            return sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const string myStreamName = "template-v1-kinesis-####-64-sandbox-customerstream14D5928D-####";

            try
            {

                DescribeStreamRequest describeStreamReq = new DescribeStreamRequest();
                describeStreamReq.StreamName = myStreamName;

                var describeResult = kinesisClient.DescribeStreamAsync(describeStreamReq).Result;
                string streamStatus = describeResult.StreamDescription.StreamStatus;
                Console.Error.WriteLine("  - current state: " + streamStatus);
                if (streamStatus == StreamStatus.ACTIVE)
                {
                     GetShardIteratorRequest sR = new GetShardIteratorRequest();
                foreach (var shardid in describeResult.StreamDescription.Shards)
                {                    

                sR.ShardId = shardid.ShardId;
                sR.ShardIteratorType = ShardIteratorType.TRIM_HORIZON;
                sR.StreamName = myStreamName;
                GetShardIteratorResponse sresp = kinesisClient.GetShardIterator(sR);
                GetRecordsRequest req = new GetRecordsRequest();
                req.ShardIterator = sresp.ShardIterator;
                //req.Limit = 100;
                
               
                GetRecordsResponse res = kinesisClient.GetRecords(req);

                foreach (var item in res.Records)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(item.PartitionKey + " : " + GetStringFromMemoryStream(item.Data));

                }
                }

                Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }
            catch (ResourceInUseException)
            {
                Console.Error.WriteLine("Producer is quitting without creating stream " + myStreamName +
                    " to put records into as a stream of the same name already exists.");
                Environment.Exit(1);
            }


        }
    }
```

2> Fiddler request and body

```
POST https://kinesis.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/ HTTP/1.1
X-Amz-Target: Kinesis_20131202.DescribeStream
User-Agent: aws-sdk-dotnet-45/2.3.55.2 .NET Runtime/3.-1 .NET Framework/Unknown OS/6.2.9200.0 ClientAsync
Host: kinesis.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
X-Amz-Date: 20210925T050415Z
X-Amz-Content-SHA256: 3fdc5c4caaa0d1cae4451b629c2fe2a56ab4d120a88197####73c62a1d2b88e
Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=##G6B52DCCPJS7 key id##/20210925/us-east-1/kinesis/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=content-type;host;user-agent;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date;x-amz-target, Signature=##9fb1076aeb342bd4b5ff9bcd131##ba02dcd0316cef4dcb0db882c##
Accept: application/json
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/x-amz-json-1.1
Content-Length: 95
Request body
{"StreamName":"template-v1-kinesis-##-64-sandbox-customerstream1##28D-VfyuboNK##p0"}
```

Note : # need to replace correct value , you can extract carefully from ARN.

Comment: if you face problem to extracting # 
follow 3 steps
1. install and run fiddler to watch http request 
2. run c# program
3. you will get http request header in fiddler
4. use header and body and run from fiddler

Comment: The above code may not return all the data since you need to loop thru the shard iterator. After executing `GetRecordsResponse res = await kinesisClient.GetRecordsAsync(req);` you can call `res.NextShardIterator` to get the next postion.